# Proper and definitive explanation about how to build a CNN 1D in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Ciao,

this is the second part of a problem I'm facing with CNN 1d. The first part is this

[How does it works the input_shape variable in Conv1d in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554413/how-does-it-works-the-input-shape-variable-in-conv1d-in-keras/57554644#57554644)

I'using this code:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D
import numpy as np

N_FEATURES=5
N_TIMESTEPS=10
X = np.random.rand(100, N_FEATURES)
Y = np.random.randint(0,2, size=100)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=N_TIMESTEPS, activation='relu', input_shape=(N_TIMESTEPS, N_FEATURES)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now, what I want to do?

> I want to train a CNN 1d over a timeseries with 5 features. Actually I want to work with time windows og length N_TIMESTEPS rather than timeserie it self. This means that I want to use a sort of "magnifier" of dimension N_TIMESTEPS x N_FEATURES on the time series to work locally. That's why I've decided to use CNN

Here come the first question. It is not clear at all if I have to transform the time series into a tensor or it is something that Keras will do for me since I've specified the **kernel_size** variable.

In case I must provide a tensor I would do something like this:

```py
X_tensor = []
for i in range(len(X)-N_TIMESTEPS):
    X_tensor+=[X_tensor[range(i, N_TIMESTEPS+i), :]]
X_tensor = np.asarray(X_tensor)
```

In this case of course I should also provide a **Y_tensor** vector computed from **Y** according to some criteria. Suppose I have already this **Y_tensor** boolean vector of the same length of **X_tensor**, which is **len(X)-N_TIMESTEPS-1**.

```py
Y_tensor = np.random.randint(0,2,len(X)-N_TIMESTEPS-1)
```

Now if I try to feed the model I get of the most common error for CNN 1d which is:

```py
  ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 5)
```

By looking to a dozen of posts about it I cannot understand what I did wrong. This is what I've tried:

```py
model.fit(X,Y)
model.fit(np.expand_dims(X, axis=0),Y)
model.fit(np.expand_dims(X, axis=2),Y)
model.fit(X_tensor,Y_tensor)
```

For all of these cases I get always the same error (with different dimensional values in the final tuple).

Questions:

> 1. What Keras expects from my data? Can I feed the model with the whole time series or I have to slice it into a tensor?
> 2. How I have to feed the model in term of data structure?I.e. I have to specify in some strange way the dimension of the data?

Can you help me? I find out that this is one the most confusing point of CNN implementation in Keras that there are different posts with different solutions that do not fit with structure of my data (even if they have a very common structure according to me).

**Note**: There are some post suggesting to pass in the **input_shape** variable the length of the data. This is meaningless to me since I should not provide the dimension of the data (which is a variable) to the model. The only thing I should give to it, according to the theory, is the filter dimension and number of features (namely the dimension of the matrix that will roll over the time series).

Thanks,

am

Answer (score 1):

Simply, `Conv1D` requires 3 dimensions:

- Number of series (1)
- Number of steps (100 - your entire data)
- Number of features (5)

So, `model.fit(np.expand_dims(X, axis=0),Y)` is correct for `X`.

Now, if `X` is `(1, 100, 5)`, naturally your `input_shape=(100,5)`.

If your `Y` has 100 steps, then you need to make sure your `Conv1D` will output 100 steps. You need `padding='same'`, otherwise it will become `91`. (I suggest you actually work with 91, since you want a result for each 10 steps and probably don't want border effects spoiling your results)

`Y` must also follow the same rules for shape:

- Number of series (1)
- Number of steps (100 if `padding='same'`; 91 if `padding='valid'`)
- Number of features (1 = Dense output)

So, `Y = Y.reshape((1,-1,1))`.

Since you have only one class (true/false), it's pointless to use `'categorical_crossentropy'`. You should go with `'binary_crossentropy'`.

In general, your overall idea of using this convolution with `kernel_size=10` to simulate sliding windows of 10 steps will work as expected (whether it will be efficient or not is another question, answered only by trying).

---

If you want better networks for sequences, you should probably try `LSTM` layers. The dimensions work exactly the same way. You will need `return_sequences=False`.

The main difference is that you will need to separate the data as you did in that loop. Then:

- `X.shape == (91, 10, 5)`
- `Y.shape == (91, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a clear idea on how 1d convolutional neural networks work:

if you want to predict the y values from the timeseries x and you just have 1 timeseries, your approach won't work. the network needs lots of samples to train, and having just 1 will allow it to easily memorize the input and not learn. For example, if the timeseries is the humidity of a given day, and y is the chance of rain at a specific timestep, what you have now is the data for just one day (timesteps being for example hours of the day). In order for the network to learn you need to gather data for many days, ending up with datasets of shape x=(n_days, timesteps, features) y=(n_days, timesteps, 1).

If you describe your actual problem there's better chance to get more helpful answers

[Edit] by sticking to your code, and using just one timeseries, you are better off with other methods that don't involve deep learning. You could split your timeseries at regular interval, obtaining n samples that would allow your network to train, but unless you have a very long timeseries that may not be a valid alternative.