# ValueError at model.fit in Keras conv1D (expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am doing a simple conv1D model. While doing model.fit, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (10, 5)
```

The base example I used is from this SO answer - [How does it works the input_shape variable in Conv1d in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554413/how-does-it-works-the-input-shape-variable-in-conv1d-in-keras)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D
import numpy as np

N_FEATURES=5
N_TIMESTEPS=10
X = np.random.rand(100, N_FEATURES)
Y = np.random.randint(0,2, size=100)

# Create a Sequential model
model = Sequential()
# Change the input shape to input_shape=(N_TIMESTEPS, N_FEATURES)
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=N_TIMESTEPS, activation='relu', input_shape=(N_TIMESTEPS, N_FEATURES)))
# If it is a binary classification then you want 1 neuron - Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model.fit I used was:

```
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

I did thought the data is prepared properly for the model to fit but why is this error appearing in this simple example? I am scratching my head here as I have seen a lot of this similar ValueError and I couldn't solve it (from what I gathered, this appears due to *incorrect data inputs*).

Any advise on this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: X must be 3D (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)

Comment: Sorry I am relatively new, does this mean I need to reshape `X` in this case? Do you have an example on it? Much appreciated!

Comment: No, the data was not prepared properly, where is N_TIMESTEPS in your X data?

Comment: Got it, I saw my issue here! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
N_FEATURES=5
N_TIMESTEPS=10
Batch_size =10
input_shape = (Batch_size, N_TIMESTEPS , N_FEATURES)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
model = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
32, 3, activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
print(model.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(10, 8, 32)
```